# CURL Post xml data to soap service return wsdl XML in php

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl

I am trying get response using curl request. soap service is running fine with soap-client. But using Curl I am not getting proper response.

Here is my Code sample:

```
$bookingRQ = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <Interface xmlns="http://api.hotels-vacation.com/Documentation/XML/OTA/4/2011B/" ChannelIdentifierId="HIS_VACATION_XML4H" Version="2011B" Interface="VACATION QUICK CONNECT XML 4 OTA">
            <ComponentInfo User="XMLHISJP" Pwd="5Kh86RSr" ComponentType="Hotel" />
        </Interface>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body RequestId="201505101528000000001" Transaction="OTA_HotelResRQ">
        <OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2012-05-03T15:47:24-04:00" EchoToken="2012-05-03T15:47:24-04:00" Target="Production" Version="1.000" PrimaryLangID="en">
            <HotelReservations>
                <HotelReservation RoomStayReservation="true" CreateDateTime="2012-05-03T15:47:24-04:00">
                    <UniqueID Type="14" ID="HZ10014035" />
                    <RoomStays>
                        <RoomStay>
                            <RoomTypes>
                                <RoomType RoomTypeCode="RR" />
                            </RoomTypes>
                            <RatePlans>
                                <RatePlan RatePlanCode="RPLN">
                                    <MealsIncluded MealPlanCodes="BRE" />
                                </RatePlan>
                            </RatePlans>
                            <RoomRates>
                                <RoomRate NumberOfUnits="1" EffectiveDate="2012-05-13" ExpireDate="2012-05-16" RoomTypeCode="RR" RatePlanCode="RPLN">
                                    <Rates>
                                        <Rate EffectiveDate="2012-05-13" ExpireDate="2012-05-14" RateTimeUnit="Day">
                                            <Base AmountBeforeTax="10000" AmountAfterTax="10980" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                                            <Total AmountBeforeTax="10000" AmountAfterTax="10980" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                                        </Rate>
                                        <Rate EffectiveDate="2012-05-14" ExpireDate="2012-05-16" RateTimeUnit="Day">
                                            <Base AmountBeforeTax="12000" AmountAfterTax="13050" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                                            <Total AmountBeforeTax="24000" AmountAfterTax="26100" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                                        </Rate>
                                    </Rates>
                                </RoomRate>
                            </RoomRates>
                            <GuestCounts>
                                <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="1" />
                                <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="8" Count="1" />
                            </GuestCounts>
                            <TimeSpan Start="2012-05-13" End="2012-05-16" />
                            <DepositPayments>
                                <RequiredPayment>
                                    <AcceptedPayments>
                                        <AcceptedPayment RPH="1">
                                            <PaymentCard CardType="1" CardCode="VISA" CardNumber="4321432143214327" ExpireDate="1007" />
                                        </AcceptedPayment>
                                    </AcceptedPayments>
                                    <AmountPercent Amount="130.80" />
                                    <Deadline AbsoluteDeadline="2012-12-15" />
                                </RequiredPayment>
                            </DepositPayments>
                            <BasicPropertyInfo HotelCode="105487" />
                            <ResGuestRPHs>
                                <ResGuestRPH RPH="1" />
                                <ResGuestRPH RPH="2" />
                            </ResGuestRPHs>
                            <SpecialRequests>
                                <SpecialRequest Language="en" RequestCode="114">
                                    <Text Language="en">Honeymoon</Text>
                                </SpecialRequest>
                                <SpecialRequest Language="en" RequestCode="21">
                                    <Text Language="en">Non-Smoking</Text>
                                </SpecialRequest>
                            </SpecialRequests>
                        </RoomStay>
                    </RoomStays>
                    <ResGuests>
                        <ResGuest ResGuestRPH="1" AgeQualifyingCode="10" Age="21">
                            <Profiles>
                                <ProfileInfo>
                                    <Profile ProfileType="1">
                                        <Customer>
                                            <PersonName>
                                                <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                                                <Surname>Dow</Surname>
                                            </PersonName>
                                        </Customer>
                                    </Profile>
                                </ProfileInfo>
                            </Profiles>
                        </ResGuest>
                        <ResGuest ResGuestRPH="2" AgeQualifyingCode="8" age="10">
                            <Profiles>
                                <ProfileInfo>
                                    <Profile ProfileType="1">
                                        <Customer>
                                            <PersonName>
                                                <GivenName>Neil</GivenName>
                                                <Surname>Dow</Surname>
                                            </PersonName>
                                        </Customer>
                                    </Profile>
                                </ProfileInfo>
                            </Profiles>
                        </ResGuest>
                    </ResGuests>
                </HotelReservation>
            </HotelReservations>
        </OTA_HotelResRQ>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Content-type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"SOAPAction: \"OTA_HotelResRQ\"",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"Content-length: ".strlen($bookingRQ)
);


$url = 'http://chetu.volateam.com/chetu/push/soapserver/PullService.php?wsdl';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bookingRQ); 


$result = curl_exec($ch);

$xmlstring = str_replace('soap-env:', '', $result);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

I am getting wsdl XML code as response. I google it but I did not find any solution. I am getting the response as below mentioned array.

Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => PullServiceHIS
            [targetNamespace] => http://chetu.volateam.com/chetu/push/soapserver/PullService.php
        )

```
[types] => Array
    (
    )

[portType] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => PullServiceHISPort
            )

        [operation] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => OTA_HotelResRQ
                    )

                [documentation] => This method takes XML request and return a string response
                [input] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [message] => tns:OTA_HotelResRQIn
                            )

                    )

                [output] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [message] => tns:OTA_HotelResRQOut
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[binding] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => PullServiceHISBinding
                [type] => tns:PullServiceHISPort
            )

        [operation] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => OTA_HotelResRQ
                    )

                [input] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [output] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[service] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => PullServiceHISService
            )

        [port] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => PullServiceHISPort
                        [binding] => tns:PullServiceHISBinding
                    )

            )

    )

[message] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => OTA_HotelResRQIn
                    )

                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => bookingRQ
                                [type] => xsd:string
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => OTA_HotelResRQOut
                    )

                [part] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => return
                                [type] => xsd:string
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the Native PHP SoapClient class. The easiest way then is to use a WSDL to php generator that will help you modelize the structures to be sent as the request.

You must also know that OTA can be complex to call and requires a really good understanding of the rquest structure.

Take a look at https://www.wsdltophp.com